operators for managing debug output
I have written a class for generating debug messages as console output like so.
class mDebug 
{
    std::ostringstream logStream;

public:

    mDebug();
    mDebug(const mDebug& other);
    ~mDebug();

    template <typename T>
    mDebug& operator<<(const T& value) {logStream << value; return *this;}
};

It contains a templated catchall << operator that allows me to write neat debug output of primitive types like so.
  mDebug() << 1.2 << "hello";

True debugging power unfolds when I implement global debug operators for the more complex objects I have in my framework, for example for a Vector:
mDebug operator<<(mDebug dbg, const Vector<T> &o)
{
    dbg << "sz:" << o.size() << " | ";
    dbg << "[";
    if (o.size() > 1)
        for (uint i = 0; i < o.size()-1; i++)
            dbg << o[i] << ",";
    if (o.size() > 0)
        dbg << o[o.size()-1];
    dbg << "]";
    return dbg;
}

and then I can
Vector<double> vec;
vec << 1.2 << 1.3 << 1.4;
mDebug() << vec;

Cool. The one thing left that doesn't let me sleep at night is that the global mDebug Vector operator takes and returns a copy of the debug stream rather than a reference. I would much prefer to have it like so
mDebug& operator<<(mDebug& dbg, const Vector<T> &o)

but then a compilation error happens that says:

error: no match for ‘operator<<’ (operand types are ‘std::ostringstream’ {aka ‘std::__cxx11::basic_ostringstream’} and ‘const Vector’) 
30 |         logStream << value; 
|         ~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~

Apparently, the member operator mDebug& operator<<(const T& value) has taken precedence over the global mDebug operator<<(mDebug& dbg, const Vector<T> &o) operator and my "catchall" function now also catches the Vector and tries to stream it directly into logStream, which won't work. I don't really understand the order of things here. How can I accomplish that all my objects can be streamed into my mDedug class using global operators while passing references AND have the catchall function declared for all primitive types?

With mDebug() << vec; you will create a temporary mDebug object, and references can't be bound to temporary objects.

Side note : adding debug message to your code you can change the behavior of the code or as you see even be a problem in itself (this gets worse when log files are in play). In general try to avoid debug messages and write unit tests instead.

Unrelated: You're missing a return statement in your first operator<<

Nice catch. Return statement fixed.

If you want to bind rvalue to reference change mDebug& to const mDebug& in the parameter.

Whenever I make my own logging system, I usually rely on the objects own overload for std::ostream. This should work for your system as well. So if you want to output your Vector<T> then create an operator template<typename T> std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, Vector<T> const&), and then use your already implemented mDebug::operator<< function.

Yes, that would work as well. I see some benefit in hiding the use of std::ostream within my mDebug class though, so I would rather write an operator<<(mDebug, myClass) for all my objects and can then change to a different logging system later on just by changing one thing within the mDebug class.
